# How to only use the first match when merging Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes: 'data' and 'working'. I am trying to merge data into working on the ID to get the Name into working

```
Data:
ID  Name
a1  a1_Name
a1  a1_Name1

Working:
ID  SomeValues 
a1  123
a1  456
```

I want the end result to match only on the first found ID each time, but as of now when I do something like

```
working = pd.merge(working, data, left_on="ID", right_on="ID", sort=False)
```

I get this:

```
Working:
ID  SomeValues Name 
a1  123        a1_Name
a1  456        a1_Name1
```

and it just alternates between 'a1_Name' and 'a1_Name1'.

I would like it to output:

```
Working:
ID  SomeValues Name 
a1  123        a1_Name
a1  456        a1_Name
```

Comment: Please post your exact expected output.

Comment: done @MayankPorwal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [3004]: Data['new_name'] = Data.groupby('ID')['Name'].transform('first')
In [3008]: Data.merge(Working, on='ID')[['ID','new_name','SomeValues']].drop_duplicates() 
Out[3008]: 
   ID new_name  SomeValues
0  a1  a1_Name         123
1  a1  a1_Name         456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first drop duplicates and then map:

```
(working.assign(Name=working['ID']
.map(data.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['Name'])))
```

---

```
   ID  SomeValues     Name
0  a1         123  a1_Name
1  a1         456  a1_Name
```

Note: you have to assign this to the same dataframe or a new dataframe as you want.